# MYSQL: foreign keys auto indexing

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, indexing

The below set of commands:

```
alter table opportunities add column ownerId int null;
alter table opportunities add foreign key (ownerId) references users (id) on delete set null on update cascade;
```

Yields an error like this:

> Error in foreign key constraint of table taous/#sql-318c_27:
>   There is no index in table "taous"."#sql-318c_27" where the columns appear
>   as the first columns. Constraint:
>   foreign key (ownerId) references users (id) on delete set null on update cascade
>   ;

So I understand that an index is lacking on the referenced column

Now, the mysql documentation for [foreign key constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) states:

> InnoDB requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan. In the referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key columns are listed as the *first* columns in the same order. Such an index is created on the referencing table automatically if it does not exist. (This is in contrast to some older versions, in which indexes had to be created explicitly or the creation of foreign key constraints would fail.) *`index_name`*, if given, is used as described previously.

I run mysql 5.1 (xampp, windows) So I expect the columns to be indexed automatically on creation of a foreign key.

Any idea why can the auto indexing fail?

One more point:
The error only happens when the sql commands are run through PDO (a db update tool). When run directly in mysql console, no problems.

Thanks

Gidi

Comment: Out of curiosity, does the user you are connecting with over PDO actually have permissions to create indexes?

Comment: Can a user be permitted to create tables but not create indexes? Anyway, I connect with root

Comment: RE: creating tables but not [indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_index): yes, those require separate privileges. Note that the host name is part of user identity; 'root'@'localhost' is a different account from 'root'@'%'. Depending on where you're connecting from, you may wind up with different privileges. Try a [`SHOW GRANTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-grants.html) command, as well as a `SELECT CURRENT_USER()` to get the full user name.

Comment: Just to make sure the obvious is not missed: the `users` table does have a primary key defined and that key consists exactly of the column `id`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thanks for questioning this, users have id as it's foreign key (the only foreign key)

Comment: @gidireich: users has to have id as the **primary** not the *foreign* key. If it's not the **primary** key, you cannot create a foreign key referencing it

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the auto-indexing is on the **referencing** table and not the **referenced** table.

In your case, the auto-indexing would add an index to `ownerId` in `opportunities`... except it doesn't need to, since you already did this.

I don't quite understand where `"taous"."#sql-318c_27"` comes from, but assuming that it relates to the `users` table, I believe the error is complaining that `id` is not indexed.

Answer (score 0):

Another cause of this error could be that the types of the the referenced and referencing table columns do not match.

For example if the the `ownerId` column of the `opportunities` table is an `INT` but the `Id` column of the `users` is any type other than `INT`

That doesn't explain why it would work with the console and not a PDO however, but maybe this helps someone else down the line.